# C# de-serialising JSON to various types

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm currently working on a c# app that is communicating with a node.js server via JSON.  I'm using [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to do the deserialisation.

**My problem is that the JSON messages are of various types (it's not known which until the message comes in), and I need to deserialise to the correct type depending on which type of message it is.**

**Is there an elegant approach to this?**  Possible (non-ideal) solutions that have occurred to me include some kind of 'all encompasing' message DTO type which any message can be deserialised to (not nice); or some kind of 'message in a message' where a message type identifier is deserialsed, and then a sub-message is then deserialsed to a specific type, but I feel there must be a better way.

I'm limited to .Net 3.5, so can't use the `dynamic` keyword.

Thank you

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/19308474

Comment: you can send some form of a tuple from node.js to the client. first item would be the json itself and a second could be a name of a class you need to deserialize to. on a client side you could use reflection to get a type from the name, or something else.

Comment: @haim770 - thanks! That worked great for me (a json.net solution to the problem).  Not sure what to do with this question now.  If you wanted to add a short generic answer along those lines I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

the node server must send Type of json on each response.the other solution is using Dynamic types on this way:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JSONtext)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do this without changes to the server, and can't use `dynamic` (stuck with .net 3.5)

Comment: The guy mentioned that he cannot use dynamic, because he is using. Net 3.5